# UVM End of test Objection Mechanism and Phase Ready to End Implementation

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am exploring different ways to end a UVM test. One method that has come often from studying different blogs from Verification Academy and other sites is to use the **Phase Ready to End**. I have some questions regarding the implementation of this method.

I am using this method in scoreboard class, where my understanding is after my usual run phase is finished, it will call the **phase ready to end** method and implement it. The reason I am using it my scoreboard's run_phase finishes early, and there are some data into queues that need to be processed. So I am trying to prolong this scoreboard run_phase using this method. Here are is some pseudo-code that I have used.

```
function void phase_ready_to_end(uvm_phase phase);
 if (phase.get_name() != "run") return;
 if (queue.size() != 0) begin
  phase.raise_objection(.obj(this)); 
  fork 
    begin 
     delay_phase(phase);
    end
  join_none
 end
endfunction

task delay_phase(uvm_phase phase);
 wait(queue.size() == 0);
 phase.drop_objection(.obj(this));
endtask
```

I have taken inspiration for this implementation from this link [UVM-End of Test Mechanism](https://blog.verificationgentleman.com/2016/03/an-overview-of-uvm-end-of-test-mechanisms.html) for your reference. Here are some of the ungated thoughts in my mind on which I need guidance and help.

1. to the best of my understanding the phase_ready_to_end is called at the end of run_phase and when it runs it raises the objection for that scoreboard run_phase and runs **delay_phase** task.
2. That Delay Phase task is just waiting for the queue to end, but I am not seeing any method or task which will pop the items from the queue. **Does I have to call some method to pop from the queue or as according to the 1st point above the raised objection will start the run phase so there is no need for that and we have to wait for a considerable amount of time?**

Let me give you some pre-context to this question. I have a scoreboard where there are two queues whose write methods are implemented and they are being fed correctly by their source.

```
task run_phase (uvm_phase phase);
 forever begin
   compare_queues(); // this method takes data from two queues and compares them, both queues implementation are fine and they take data from their respective sources. Let me give you a scenario, let's suppose there are a total of 10 transactions being generated but the scoreboard was able to process only 6 of them and there are 4 transactions left when all objections are dropped. So to tackle that I implement this phase_to_ready_end method in my scoreboard. 
end
endtask
```

The problem with this method that I am having is that, when I raise the objection in this phase_ready_to_end and call delay_phase method, nothing happens. And I am curious is there more to this implementation or not?

---

Sorry for the delay. I have shared more context to the existing question. Please see to that, let me know if it is confusing.

1. We have a pair of monitors that calls write method implemented inside the scoreboard. The monitors typically capture the transaction from BUS and call these WR methods to push the transactions. Thus two source and destination monitors WR into two - source and destination - queues as and when they find the transactions.
2. We have a checker task with RD-n-check running in forever loop in the run-phase of scoreboard. It's in a while loop and watches if the destination queue has non-zero entry. Once it finds so, it pops the head entry from destination queue and then pops the head entry from source queue as well and compares the two entries to declare if the check was a PASS or FAIL.
3. There are more than 2 queues and more than a pair of source/destination of course, but broadly this is the architecture around here.
4. Now in the current scenario, it seems that the checker tasks stop prints after certain point of time in some of the test cases. Upon adding debug prints thoroughly, it seems that checker tasks that does the job #2/#3 above and gets called inside the forever loop of the run-phase, exits gracefully one last time. However they are entered again - which is to say that the forever  loop that should be calling them didn't call. As if the forever loop of run-phase stopped completely.
5. We also added another forever loop in run-phase that observes whether the queues are empty. From prints inside that parallel loop and from the monitor prints, we know that the queues aren't empty and monitors did push WRs into the queues for a long time.
6. It seems that the forever loop stopped working suddenly ( going by prints spewed out) all of a sudden but another set of threads that we added in runphase in another forever loop just to monitor those queues - keep printing that the queues have contents. So run-phase shouldn't be over but the checker tasks running in forever has stopped.
7. We are using Vivado 2020.2 for the simulation. This is a baffling/weird problem for us and we did go through prints multiple times to make sure nothing has been missed out. It seems we are missing very very basic or has hit a bug/broken some basics of UVM coding to land into here.

If you have any help, thoughts here, will appreciate that greatly.

Answer (score 3):

The function `phase_ready_to_end()` gets called at the end of every task-based phase when all objections have been dropped (or never raised at all).

Typically a scoreboard has a queue or some kind of array of transactions waiting to be checked sent from a monitor via an analysis_port `write()` method. If your scoreboard is an in-order comparison checker, the queue size is zero when there are no more transactions waiting to be received.

If you look at the code in the link you shared, there is the following in the `write_south` method doing exactly that:

```
if (!item.compare(item_stream.pop_front()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave, The thing is that I think I'm not able to clarify my question, I have all the items there in my scoreboard class regarding queues and their write methods.

Comment: hello dave_59 I have added more context to the question? can you check and see if it makes more sense

Comment: @abdulrauf, It does not really help. You need debug your queue to find out why it is not being emptied.